# Why is it possible to solve this equation by setting a greater than 0 and not equal to 0?

Tags: equation-solving

Why is there no solution for the system of equations with a greater than 0?

```
Solve[{c^2 - b^4/a^2 == 0, a^2 + b^2 == c^2, e == c/a, a > 0, 
  e > 1}, e, {a, c}]
```

Why can we solve the value of e by setting a not equal to 0?

```
Solve[{c^2 - b^4/a^2 == 0, a^2 + b^2 == c^2, e == c/a, a != 0, 
  e > 1}, e, {a, c}]
```

```
{{e -> 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])}}
```

How can we solve this equation if a is greater than 0?

```
Solve[{(((2 Sqrt[2] + 2) a)^2 + 8 a^2 - 4 c^2)/(
   2 (2 Sqrt[2] + 2) a 2 Sqrt[2] a) == Sqrt[2]/2, e == c/a, a > 0, 
  e > 1}, e, {a, c}]
```

the result is:

```
{{e -> Sqrt[3]}}
```

Comment: `Solve[{c^2 - b^4/a^2 == 0, a^2 + b^2 == c^2, e == c/a, a > 0, 
  e > 1}, e, {a, c}, Reals]`

Comment: The result of `Solve[{c^2 - b^4/a^2 == 0, a^2 + b^2 == c^2, e == c/a, a > 0, 
  e > 1}, e, {a, b}, Reals]` is more informative.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I would report it to "support@wolfram.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no solutions with generic complex b -- Im[b] needs to be zero.

```
In[1]:= Solve[{c^2 - b^4/a^2 == 0, a^2 + b^2 == c^2, e == c/a, a > 0, e > 1}, e, {a,
 c}, MaxExtraConditions->1]//InputForm                                              

Out[1]//InputForm= 
{{e -> ConditionalExpression[(1 + Sqrt[5])/2, (Im[b] == 0 && Re[b] > 0) || 
     (Im[b] == 0 && Re[b] < 0)]}}
```

There is a solution with generic real b.

```
In[2]:= Solve[{c^2 - b^4/a^2 == 0, a^2 + b^2 == c^2, e == c/a, a > 0, e > 1}, e, {a,
 c}, Reals]//InputForm                                                              

Out[2]//InputForm= {{e -> (1 + Sqrt[5])/2}}
```

Comment: ```Solve[{c^2 - b^4/a^2 == 0, a^2 + b^2 == c^2, e == c/a, a != 0, 
  e > 1}, e, {a, b, c}]```

Comment: ```Solve[{c^2 - b^4/a^2 == 0, a^2 + b^2 == c^2, e == c/a, a > 0, 
  e > 1}, e, {a, b, c}]```

Comment: After your explanation, we know that the solution of this equation is related to whether the parameter b is a complex number whose imaginary part is not equal to 0. The value of e can be calculated successfully in the above two forms. {a,b,c}

Answer (score 2):

I opine that your original problem was poorly stated.

I took the liberty of restating yor problem after noting the $e$ could computed afterwards:

```
solution = Reduce[{c^2 - b^4/a^2 == 0, a^2 + b^2 == c^2, 
c/a > 0, a > 0}, {a, b, c}, Reals]
```

I used Reduce to attempt to avail all the solutions.

```
ConditionalExpression[{ToRules[solution[[2]]]}, a > 0]
```

$$\fbox{$\left\{\left\{b\to -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{5} \sqrt{a^4}+\frac{a^2}{2}},c\to \frac{b^2}{a}\right\}, \\ 
\left\{b\to \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{5} \sqrt{a^4}+\frac{a^2}{2}},c\to \frac{b^2}{a}\right\}\right\}\text{ if }a>0$}$$

```
ConditionalExpression[{{b -> -Sqrt[a^2/2 + (1/2)*Sqrt[5]*Sqrt[a^4]], c -> b^2/a}, {b -> Sqrt[a^2/2 + (1/2)*Sqrt[5]*Sqrt[a^4]], c -> b^2/a}}, a > 0]
```

Of course, I may have missed something.